# Doubt in proving sample mean is unbiased estimator of population mean in case of SRSWOR.

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, sampling

I am sharing a proof encountered in William Cochran(1977: page 22): Sampling Techniques.The sample mean $\bar y$ is an unbiased estimate of the population mean $μ$ in a simple random sampling (SRS) process while sampling without replacement.
He starts with

$$E(\bar y) = \frac{\sum_{}\bar y}{_N C _n} = \frac{\sum_{} y_1+y_2+y_3+....+y_n}{n[N!/n!(N-n)!]}$$

**My explanation of this part is: He calculates expectation where $\dfrac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} $ is probability of choosing a sample.**

To evaluate this sum, we find out in how many samples any specific value $y_i$ appears. Since there are $(N-1)$ other units available for the rest of the sample and $(n-1)$ other places left in our sample, the number of samples containing $y_i$ is

This above statements I copied from book and I didn't understand.

$$\overbrace {_{N-1} C _{n-1} = \frac{(N-1)!}{(n-1)!(N-n)!]}}$$

$$\underbrace{\sum_{} y_1+y_2+y_3+....+y_n = \frac{(N-1)!}{(n-1)!(N-n)!]}(y_1+y_2+y_3+....+y_n)}$$

Plug this into the first equation and obtain:

$${E(\bar y) = \frac{(N-1)!}{(n-1)!(N-n)!]} \frac{n!(N-n)!}{nN!}(y_1+y_2+y_3+....+y_n)}$$

This simplifies to:

$$E(\bar y) = \frac{(y_1+y_2+y_3+....+y_n)}{N} $$

This is equal to $\mu$. 
I don't understand the portion in braces please can someone help me understand it using an example thoroughly.

Here is [a screenshot of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onhDP.png).

Comment: Please avoid [linking to external images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4376/259305), which would be inaccessible in case of external server down.  Please use SE's internal image instead.  Btw, +1 for having [typed out everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327840/259305)

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I ll keep it mind.